# Error while setting up Spring Data JPA Read-Only Repository

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot: `1.3.0.RC1`

Spring Boot Starter JPA: `1.3.0.RC1`

Having an issue with setting up a Spring Data JPA Read Only Repository.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    T findOne(ID id);
    Iterable<T> findAll();
    Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Using IntelliJ 15 I am getting this compile error:

```
Error:(16, 83) java: type org.springframework.stereotype.Repository does not take parameters
```

The error points at this bit of code: `Repository<T, ID>`

Has something changed within Spring Data JPA? Am I doing something wrong?

Following examples as listed here: [Fine-tuning Spring Data repositories](http://spring.io/blog/2011/07/27/fine-tuning-spring-data-repositories/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error points in the right direction.  IntelliJ 15 when using `ctrl` `space` pulls the Repository Stereotype `import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository` rather than the correct `import org.springframework.data.repository`.

If you type quickly and don't notice the wrong import you will receive the error above.